# Am I confusing macro-expansion with evaluation?

Tags: common-lisp, slime

CLHS says `and` is a macro.

So I was interested in how it was implemented and used slime's `slime-macroexpand-all-inplace` to expand `(and 1 2 nil 4 5)` which yields:

```
(IF 1
    (IF 2
        (IF NIL
            (IF 4
                (THE T 5)
                NIL)
            NIL)
        NIL)
    NIL)
```

What I don't understand is that `and` supposedly stops evaluating as soon as it encounters a `nil` value. But here `and` is looking beyond `...(IF NIL...`

Am I confusing macro-expansion with evaluation?

I also tried to trace the evaluation of `(and 1 2 nil 4 5)` with `C-c C-t` but slime (or sbcl) complains: `can't use encapsulation to trace anonymous function #<FUNCTION (MACRO-FUNCTIONAND) {2264360D}>`

Comment: In your expanded code when any of the predicates evaluated to `nil` it goes to the alternative which is `nil` without evaluating more predicates. In your example `4` and `5` are never evaluated.

Comment: You're right. `4` and `5` simply are part of the *then clause* of the third `if`. I was just confused because I expected a receding line after `(IF NIL` but that would make no sense. Thank you.
So from a performance point of view: Even if it doesn't have to evaluate more predicates -- because of the nested structure it still has to propagate the `nil` two more times, doesn't it?

Comment: No. If `1` is true (which it is) the else clause it has is never evaluated. Thus only the `nil` in the else clause of the `if` that turns out false is evaluated and the result of the whole nested `if` form. In terms of evaluation it evaluates `1`, `2`, `nil`, `nil` (the last is the result).

Comment: I see, ok, thank you.

Comment: A reasonable compiler would eliminate all the unreachable code after the "if nil" part. But macroexpansion isn't concerned with that level, only with generating code.